# Azure SQL metric

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, metrics

I am not able to find few SQL metrics in Azure. Can anyone help in how to set metrics for below topics.

1)Under utilized capacity

2)Number of databases outside of pool

3)Scale up

4)Connection timeout

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, these are not standard or traditional metrics of Azure SQL database. Some of the "metrics" which we could not see and change it directly.

**>1.Under utilized capacity**

Each Azure SQL database has the [price tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers-dtu) and DTUs/vCore model. This depend the SQL database capacity. Azure SQL database provided Metirc feature to help us see how many  capacity we used. Please see this doucument: [Monitoring and tuning capabilities in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-monitor-tune-overview#monitoring-and-tuning-capabilities-in-the-azure-portal).

[image]

**>2.Number of databases outside of pool**

We can't see this "metric". The only thing we can do is that get all the member databases in the Elastic Pool.

Ref here: [Databases - List By Elastic Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/Databases/ListByElasticPool#examples):

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{serverName}/elasticPools/{elasticPoolName}/databases?api-version=2017-10-01-preview
```

**>3.Scale up**

Scale up also is not a Azure SQL database metric. That's a feature of Azure SQL Database enables you to easily scale you database by adding more compute power (scale-up) or adding more database units (scale-out). Ref: [Scale Up/Down](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-scale-resources).

You also could scale up you singe database like bellow ways:

1. [Scale single database resources in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-single-database-scale)
2. [Use PowerShell to monitor and scale a single SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-monitor-and-scale-database-powershell)

**>4.Connection timeout**

Connection timeout is the property usually set in the connection string(for app connecting) or when connect to SQL database in Database manage tools. The default value is "30"s. When connect to Azure SQL database delay time is out of 30s, we will get the timeout error.

Get the connection string on Portal:

[image]

Set the connection timeout in SSMS:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have so many SQL databases and it is not possible to create alert by SQL database wise. So is there any other easy way to apply the metric alert by SQL server name in one resource group

Comment: @GayathriK No, there isn't. Azure SQL server  host the databases and doesn't has these "metrics". The only thing we can get from Azure SQL Server is the `DTU quota`(you could see it on Portal), this may help you how many DTU used for the SQL server.  As I said, these are not standard or traditional metrics of Azure SQL database, we can't get all these "metrics" directly and from one tool.

Comment: @GayathriK I don't know how to get the Azure SQL server `DTU quota` from other tools, seams only supported by Portal  In the end, If my answer is helpful for you, can you please mark it as answe?. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: 4) Connection Timeout: I want to know what requests are failed due to connection timed out

Comment: @GayathriK It's hard to say, maybe the internet delay or other reason.